# Is a Hexblade's weapon damage still magical if I choose not to use Charisma?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, magic, warlock, damage

If I choose to use the Dex mod instead of Charisma (as per the Hexblade's Hex Warrior feature) for my ranged pact weapon, will the weapon's damage still be magical damage?

Comment: How are you getting a non-magical ranged pact weapon?  Relevant SA: https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-april-2016. The crossbow would need to be a magic weapon to become your pact weapon in the first place.

Comment: Are you asking about a non-pact weapon used with the Hex Warrior feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Hex Warrior does not affect the type of damage.

### The Hex Warrior feature does not cause a weapon to inflict magic damage.

The hex warrior feature allows the warlock to select a particular weapon and apply their charisma modifier for attack and damage rolls instead of strength or dexterity.

The hex warrior feature automatically applies to *pact of the blade* weapons for the warlock who has both features, but the hex warrior feature does not need to be applied to a pact weapon.

### Pact of the Blade

The weapon used for pact of the blade is either a transformed magical weapon, where the damage was magical to begin with, or it is a manifested weapon that "counts as magical for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to non-magical attacks and damage."  So all pact weapons inflict magical damage.

#### Ranged Pact Weapon

There are two ways of getting a ranged pact weapon: transforming an existing magical weapon, or taking the *Improved Pact Weapon* invocation which allows creating ranged pact weapons.  As above with the melee pact weapons, the created weapons inflict magic damage for the purposes of resistance and immunity, while a transformed magic weapon is already magic to begin with.

Relevant [Sage Advice](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-april-2016).

Comment: "In order to have a non-melee pact weapon, it must be a transformed magical weapon"

The Improved Pact Weapon invocation lets you conjure non-melee pact weapons, so that's not quite true.

Comment: @Cubic Thanks.  I'll update accordingly

Answer (score 5):

[As GcL notes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149652/is-a-hexblades-weapon-damage-still-magical-if-i-choose-not-to-use-charisma/149655#149655), the Hex Warrior feature does not cause a weapon's damage to count as magical. That is caused by the Pact of the Blade feature, which can only conjure a melee weapon or a magic weapon that you have transformed into your pact weapon via a special ritual, as described in the feature description.

However, *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* describes the **Improved Pact Weapon** invocation:

> Finally, the weapon you conjure can be a shortbow, longbow, light crossbow, or heavy crossbow.

If you conjure a shortbow, longbow, light crossbow, or heavy crossbow as your pact weapon using the Improved Pact Weapon invocation, it automatically gains the benefits of the Hex Warrior feature, but whether you choose to use your Str/Dex modifier or your Charisma modifier, **its damage will still count as magical as it is your Pact weapon**.

Comment: Welcome to the site @DucksGoMooful (though I see you've been a member for a year or so)! You've had a great couple of answers here already and we hope you'll stick around and contribute more.

Comment: Also I'm not sure anybody has mentioned it, but you now have enough reputation to join and post in [RPG chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) where we hang out and discuss things. Feel to drop in and chat. :)